# How do I create a UIImageview from within a custom class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I am an objective C newb and relative programming novice in general, so your patience is appreciated.  Inside a View Based Application template I am pulling this code out of myNameViewController.m and trying to insert it into a custom class.  Everything transitions fine except this: [self.view addSubview:myImage];  I gather this is now calling the addSubview method of myObject, which does not exist....what is the correct way to insert the subview into the current view?

```
#import "myObject.h"

@implementation myObject

-(void)drawImage{

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0f, 70.0f);
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
    myImage.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];
}

@end
```

Comment: if there is anything I can clarify with my answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have copied is deriving from *UIViewController* (which is where the *view* property is defined). *addSubview* is a message on the *UIView* object.

So your *myObject* needs to be a subclass of *UIViewController* so that you can access its child view, or perhaps *myObject* is just a view on it's own (does *myObject* derive from *UIView* ?), in which case you can just add the *UIImageView* to the view hierarchy for *myObject*:

```
[self addSubview:myImage];
```

**Update**

You need to implement the *drawRect* message in your UIView subclass and draw on [context](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html).  So something like:

```
@implementation ViewWhichDrawsItself

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    // get the drawing context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext ();

    // draw on the context
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Cannondale, many thanks for your response.  Would you be so kind as to post some example code of a UIView subclass object that can draw itself?  I couldn't find any examples on the web or in the Apple documentation about how to do this...thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myObject` has to be a subclass of `UIViewController` for this to work, since this will give it the `view` property (same as the `viewController` you've copied the code from.

In `myObject.h`, your interface should read:

```
@interface myObject : UIViewController {
```

}

which means that it *subClasses*, or becomes a `UIViewController` at heart. It can do anything a regular `UIViewController` can do and will inherit all the same properties (such as a `view`), but since it only subclasses it you are able to add extra information that is *specific to your own object*.